# Export only certain column on single table to csv format

Tags: mysql, database-design, csv

### I need to export certain column only of a database table to csv file.

Here is the format of the *source*:

ID | user_email | user_login | user_nickname | usergroup | address | user_registered | user_url

---

And this should be the *output* format:

ID | user_login | user_nickname | user_email | user_url | user_registered

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide more information please? Like what have you tried already, what errors (if any) are you getting? Share any code you may have. People are more willing to help you if you have at least attempted to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT ((just those columns)) INTO OUTFILE ...`

Answer (score -1):

By example :

`SELECT email FROM users INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/web.csv';`